# Regex result capturing case

Tags: c#, regex

If I have input strings of the type `((a|b)\\.([a-zA-Z]+)|c)`, how must I do the capturing of split results so that the following test cases work?

```
a.hello yields '', 'a', 'hello', ''
b.tmr   yields '', 'b', 'tmr', ''
c       yields '', 'c', None, ''
```

Thanks

Comment: What programming language does this concern?

Comment: The particular language I am using now is c#. But this question pertains to any language that supports regular expression. I will prob put a C# tag.

Comment: @Discretizer some frameworks have differences when interpreting regex, just fyi

Comment: Thanks DLeh. I want to work in C# framework. I have added the tag. Please let me know if the above split results are possible. I don't know how to use (?:) and () together to get the above results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work

```
()(?:((?:a|b))\.(\w+)|(c)())()
```

`It matches:`

[image]

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tS9gW7/1)

Comment: Works perfectly. And thanks for the site. It is a great place to check stuff quickly.

Comment: @Discretizer , Welcome :) Yeah it is :)